# Convert multiple categorical variables to factors in R

Tags: r, neural-network, dataset, categorical-data

Salutations

Currently creating a neural network, and need to have the data structured properly. For one of the data columns, there is string data that needs to be converted to a numeric. Only problem is, is that the string data in each row is  example `QWERTGCD, AWERTKRD, TWERTKRR'`etc. There is over 1000 lines of rows, each one having the same or different strings like in the example posted. I dont know how to convert multiple strings, into categorical data on this scale. Same thing goes for the labels partion.

So far I have this to start with

`dataset$Box = as.numeric(factor(dataset$Box, levels = c(), labels = c()))`

Not sure if I am overthinking this, but I cant figure how exactly to input the levels and tables without painstakingly going through the data, and inputing in myself.

Here's an example of the data that being worked with.

`B,11979,13236,1261,3,QWERTGCD,1 
 B,475514,476069,559,33,QWERTOOD,1
 C,65534,65867,337,1,QWERAEER,1
 C,73738,74657,923,2,AWERTWED,1`

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to *Stack Overflow*, in order that we can help you, please provide example data and the steps you've tried so far. Consider [*How to make a great reproducible example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038), thank you.

Comment: A good reproducible example involves code that will produce an object that has all the characteristics of the object you're having a problem with, so that the solution to your problem can be applied to the example object you've provided. Here, if your data is a data frame, you should provide example data that is a data frame. If it's a matrix, you should provide a matrix. If it's a raw set of comma separated values, then you have more to work on before getting to this question (how do you convert a column of data from character to numeric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, it's hard to know exactly what you need, but in general, one thing R is good at is running operations on entire columns all at once. You're just converting a column in `dataset` that is named `Box` from a string to numeric, going through a factor.  `factor()` finds all the unique values in your column for you. So you don't need to specify them.

```
dataset$Box <- as.numeric(factor(dataset$Box))
```

will take the `Box` column in dataset and convert it from class `character` to class `numeric`, numbering the character values in `Box` in alphanumeric order (unless you specify otherwise). It may even already be a factor, depending on how your dataset was generated. You can check with `class(dataset$Box)`.  If that returns `factor` then you just need to run `dataset$Box <- as.numeric(dataset$Box)`